# Is there a way to ignore or globally replace NUL characters in CSVHelper?

Tags: csvhelper

We've been using CSVHelper for several years to read files, and it's brilliant. Recently we've received a couple of errors from our customers who were trying to upload their files - and it transpires that they have NUL (i.e. ASCII zero) characters in the file.

As an example, say we had the following in the input file - where NUL is actually ASCII 0...

This,That,NUL,TheOther

CSVHelper reads this line fine - and converts the NUL value to a .NET null (i.e. '\0'). We'd like to alter this behaviour, if possible, and have CSVHelper relace any instance of NUL with string.Empty.

We have considered reading the entire file once and replacing all NUL characters ourselves, but would rather do this with CSVHelper if there's an elegant way to do this. I could alter all of our class maps and override all the type converters in the box to do this, but if there is a more general purpose solution I'd rather use that.

I've looked at the CsvConfiguration.InjectionCharacters property and SanitizeForInjection might do the trick, but that looks like it just adds an escape character to the front of the field.

Any suggestions gratefully received, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to read the file with CsvHelper, replace the NUL values with string.Empty and then write the file back again?  If so I believe it would work to read the records in as a dynamic list using a custom string converter to replace the values and then write them back again to a file.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Property1,Property2,Property3,Property4");
            writer.WriteLine("This,That,\0,TheOther");
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            csv.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<string>(new NulStringConverter());

            var records = csv.GetRecords<dynamic>().ToList();       

            using(var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                csvWriter.WriteRecords(records);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class NulStringConverter : StringConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        if (text == "\0")
        {
            text = string.Empty;
        }

        return base.ConvertFromString(text, row, memberMapData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - we ended up using something similar and can now read files with embedded NUL's (although why on earth anyone would create a CSV with NUL characters is beyond me).

Comment: Thank you. Quick feedback for anyone using csvHelper 20.0.0+, replace
`csv.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<string>(new NulStringConverter());`
by
`csv.Context.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<string>(new NulStringConverter());`
Verified using version 28.0.1 and I assume from reading the changelog that the break began with version 20.0.0.